# how to insert into multi rows under single column without changing other column value in postgres postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I've tried some solution provide in this forum. that tell how to insert or update multiple rows under single column but none have work. I'm using Postgres 12 and Postgis this is my code 
TABLE :

```
(
   gid integer NOT NULL,
   line character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
   station character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
   longitude numeric,
   latitude numeric,
   easting numeric,
   northing numeric,
   geom geometry(Point,4326),
   CONSTRAINT f83_simple_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.f83_simple
   OWNER to postgres;
```

and I wanna only add values to Column geom. As I have to insert this geometry list to my curent table

```
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E610000001A2CC4DCF7624414EA1B2F172B36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E6100000F03758A5DE7424410159333276B36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E61000004D9F4C4EE17224411A07DD6578B36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E610000058BBB033E87024418CF4FD1F7BB36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E6100000B25683481D6F2441DA584A367BB36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E6100000A0317B340F6D2441D4567E857FB36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E61000006CB48FF4266B2441BA9F0C8282B36141');
insert into f83_simple (geom) values ('0101000020E6100000939F53783A692441388B10F884B36141');
```

but I alway got this ERROR message

````
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0101000020E6100000F9D634D4BB782441D7FC7D4571B36141).
SQL state: 23502```
````

Answer (score 1):

The gid column is defined with "not null".  There needs to be a value for it at least.
For example: `insert into f83_simple (gid, geom) values (1, '0101000020E610000001A2CC4DCF7624414EA1B2F172B36141');`

Comment: when I use your suggestion another error result 
```ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "f83_simple_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (gid)=(1) already exists.
SQL state: 23505```

Comment: There seems to be an unique constraint on the gid column so you cannot insert two rows with the same gid.  Set gid to 2 in the next insert, 3 the next etc.  From the looks of it, the gid is probably supposed to be an identity column so you don't have to send the gid in the insert statement.  Look at this for help on identity columns: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/

Comment: even I dont use gid as INSERT statement it seems the statement alway including gid aswel. Im using Postgres 12

Comment: The definition for gid is ```gid integer NOT NULL``` so there cannot be NULL in it.  If you don't send the gid in insert statement, it is null and the insert fails.  You need to change the definition of the column so that a value is created automatically if you don't want to send the gid in the insert statement.